# Responsive filemanager upload images with grey bar and multiple empty versions

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, responsive-filemanager

For a while now, when uploading .jpg files, I regularly have the problem that they are uploaded with a gray bar and also several empty versions.

On the image in the attachment I tried to upload 2 images with 1 image appearing 5 times of which only one works with gray bar. The second image uploads twice whose thumbnail looks fine but the large version also has a gray bar.

I have not been able to find a solution on the internet so far, are there more people who have this and know how to fix it?

[The upload problems on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3o0L.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue with the same thing happening to me.

I found the issue for me was that the PHP upload_max_filesize was set to a smaller size than the file I was uploading.